# How to add indexTitles in a collection view? (iOS 10+)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios10, ios11

As the question, I'm trying to add an "index titles" in a collection view for a fast navigation of the contents of my `UIColletionView`.

I've read that, starting from iOS 10, method like `indexTitles(for:)` and `collectionView(_:indexPathForIndexTitle:at:)` can help me in that as in the **UITableViews**. But I'm not getting any result! Have you figured out how to use those methods? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I posted a question on Apple Developer Forums https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/95644

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @PatrickBodet I haven't worked on the project since then but I've found this: https://github.com/kreeger/BDKCollectionIndexView . I'll give it a try when I'll have time but maybe it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at `UICollectionView.h`, `indexTitlesForCollectionView` is only available in tvos:

```
/// Returns a list of index titles to display in the index view (e.g. ["A", "B", "C" ... "Z", "#"])
- (nullable NSArray<NSString *> *)indexTitlesForCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView API_AVAILABLE(tvos(10.2));
```

You might have read Apple's documentation, which states that indexTitle methods are available for iOS 10.3+ and tvOS 10.2+: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/2851455-indextitles

I tried implementing it on iOS and it just doesn't work, which leads me to believe that somehow they made a mistake in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I got the titles working on iPhones only by adding the following to my data source:

```
func indexTitles(for collectionView: UICollectionView) -> [String]? {
    guard !RunUtilities.isIpad else { return nil }
    return Array(Set(objects.map{ String($0.name.prefix(1)) })).sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPathForIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> IndexPath {
    guard let index = objects.firstIndex(where: { $0.name.prefix(1) == title }) else {
        return IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    }
    return IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
}
```

EDIT: It looks like this is working from iOS 14 onwards. I installed the 13.4 runtime and the titles don't show.